# Access MAC addresses (IP to MAC - ARP) between two subnets. Seperated via router

Tags: linux, router, subnet, arp, raspbian

I've come across an issue, and after spending days investigating I've realised I need some advice. My networking skill level is still quite low.

I've got two routers, with two LANs. I've connected one of the routers to the other via a LAN <-> WAN connection, creating a separate network to contain controller and devices. The main reason for two routers is so that I can have a separate DCHP server for **Router B's** connections. See below for the image:

[image: Network]

I have access to the controller via **Router A's** network, I can get to the web based GUI to see all my devices on the network via setting the ports/virtual servers on **Router B.** However, I have code on the controller that needs to monitor devices on **Router As** LAN. The code needs access to the subnet so that it can resolve IPs to MAC addresses (ARP requests). Currently I can ping from **Router B's** devices to **Router A's** devices, but can't resolve IP to MAC addresses (I'm using NMAP). I believe this is because ARP requests only work in the same subnet.

Is it possible to add a **second static IP** in the same subnet as Router A's LAN (outside of DHCP range of A) **to the controller** on **Router B's** network, and somehow route this through **Router B** so that the requests are resolved and sent back?

If not, is there an alternative?

**Additional Information:**

**Controller :** Linux - Raspbian

**Router A:** Belkin Modem-Router

**Router B:** Edimax Router

Comment: For proper consideration of this problem, without the complaint that 'home' networks are off-topic here, you should edit the question to read 'lab' instead of home.  This really falls in the overlap between SuperUser stack and ServerFault..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that I cannot resolve MAC addresses if the controller is not directly connected to **Router As** network. Not sure if it is possible to use static routes to allow the controller ARP requests to get passed straight though to Router A's network, but it seems like a lot of manual configuration when I can configure the below and it works as desired.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfHab.png)

The only downside is that devices on **Router B's** network do not have access to the internet, but that can be solved by connecting **Router B's** WAN connection to **Router A's** Lan connection and should not cause any headaches.

With the current setup I cannot access **Router B's** web interface directly from **Router As** network, but it might be possible to configure a static route in the controller to allow access to **Router B's** gateway. Or connect **Router B** to **Router A** and just access it via a DHCP assigned IP from **Router A**.

Answer (score 0):

Network A is using one 24 bit subnet of the reserved, private (non-routeable) Class C network (192.168.x.x).  Network B is using a different network, but not within the reserved, private Class C.  If you rework it with Network B on 192.168.3.x, you may find a bit better luck.

The external connection for Network B should have an address on 192.168.2.x.  Router B (and all Network B hosts) should have that address as external gateway.  The addresses of all Network B hosts should be 192.168.3.x.  If Router B is not doing NAT, you need to set up IPTables on it to do NAT.

I think you'll also need to build static routes for A->B (on Router A) and B->A (on Router B), since you're using non-routable IPs.

Another option would be to remove Router B and replace it with a switch, and use DHCP reservations on Network A for each of the Network B systems.  Then they're all on the same IP network.